# Databricks/ADF python assistance

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks

Need help with executing python script from Azure databricks. 
Ask is to connect to databases using python script and read data from table and trigger email with the contents from table.

Here is my sample script. It works fine from my local, however i'm not sure how to make it work on Databricks or Data factory.

```
import pyodbc
import settings
import sendgrid
import time
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import *

username = settings.username
password = settings.password
server = settings.server
database = settings.database
driver= '{SQL Server}'
connection_string = 'DRIVER={driver};PORT=1433;SERVER={server};DATABASE= 
{database};
UID={username};
PWD={password}'.format(driver=driver, server=server, 
database=database, username=username, password=password)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)

cursor= cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("Select Job_status as Status, COUNT(*) AS 
count FROM demo_table group by Job_status")
arr=[]
while 1:
row = cursor.fetchone()
if not row:
break
print(row.Status, row.count)
arr.append(row.Status+" "+str(row.count))
Status = arr[0] , arr[1]
cnxn.close()

sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey='***********************')
from_email = Email("********************")
to_email = Email("****************************")
subject = "Job Monitoring | Job Failures"
content = Content("text/html", value = 'Hi,Provided are the details of the 
jobs.' +str(Status[0])+''+str(Status[1]) +'Regards,Team')
mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())"
```

Once the job is completed, It should ideally read data from the table and then trigger email with the job details.

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

I see there are two third-party Python libraries required in your code, so first you need to install them in Azure Databricks, as below.

1. Install the `sendgrid` package is relatively simple, as the figures below.

   Fig 1.1. Click the `Launch Workspace` button in Azure portal and sign in.
   [image]

   Fig 1.2. Move to the tab `Clusters` and to `Create Cluster`, and then to click the `Libraries` link of your cluster
   [image]

   Fig 1.3. Click the `Install New` button and select the `PyPI` library source to type the package name `sendgrid` to `Install`
   [image]

   Fig 1.4. Immediately the `sendgrid` package had installed
   [image]
2. Follow the blog [`Executing SQL Server Stored Procedures from Databricks (PySpark)`](https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/10/12/executing-sql-server-stored-procedures-on-databricks-pyspark) to install `pyodbc` package with its required linux-packages, as below.

   Fig 2.1. Create a new notebook `install_pyodbc` for next installation
   [image]

   Fig 2.2. To check the Linux distribution version and follow the blog to install these packages
   [image]

   Fig 2.3. Try to connect and query the database via pyodbc, it works
   [image]

   ```
   import pyodbc
   connection_string = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:<your db name>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<db name>;Uid=<username>@<dbinstance name>;Pwd=<password>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"
   cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
   cursor= cnxn.cursor()
   cursor.execute("select * from table")
   row = cursor.fetchone()
   if row:
       print(row)
   ```

Then, you can create a new notebook to run your code. And to integrate with Azure Data Factory, please refer to the offical document [`Transform data by running a Python activity in Azure Databricks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-python) to know how to do.

Comment: Thanks for the response @peter. Appreciate it!
I was able to load the Libraries and also connect to database, however i wasn't able to configure Sendgrid mail. I didn't have any errors neither did i receive any email notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you  got this thing working, but it worked as a charm for me. One remark: use

`sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient('***********************')`

instead of

`sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(**apikey=**'***********************')`

I don't know if this is version dependent, but it was the only small issue I got.